# How to create a secure connection in form fields with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http, security, sinatra

I used a front-end and back-end API server to implement a Ruby/Sinatra web application. The form will post to the '/login' route in the front-end app.rb:

```
post '/login' do
  uri = URI.join("http://#{settings.api}:#{settings.api_port}",
                 "/user/", "validate")
  response = Net::HTTP.post_form(
    uri, 'email' => params[:email], 
    'password' => params[:password])
  h = response.code == "200" || response.code == "401" ? 
      JSON.parse(response.body) : {}
  if h["status"] == "success"
    # Save the user id inside the browser cookie. 
    # This is how we keep the user 
    # logged in when they navigate around our website.
    session[:user_id] = h["user_id"]
    puts session[:user_id]
    redirect '/home'
  else
  # If user's login doesn't work, send them back to the login form.
    flash[:notice] = "Login failed due to #{h["status"]}"
    redirect '/login'
  end
end
```

The post request and its parameters are sent through HTTP to the back-end server. And the back-end API server will respond with JSON which has a status field to suggest if the user is authenticated successfully.

I have the following message in the browser that says "connection not secure".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7o67.png). Is there extra safety configuration that I have to include in the front-end app.rb?

Comment: The website can be accessed here: [link](http://157.245.142.108/login). The image doesn't show the insecure prompt message.

Comment: Please do NOT use images to provide code, data or debugging information. "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)". Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Isn't that message because you're using bare HTTP? Is the receiving app on a different network altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following configrations in your app.rb file:

```
configure :development, :test do
  set :force_ssl, true
end

configure :production do
  set :force_ssl, true
end
```

See "[Forcing SSL in a Sinatra App](http://gaidi.ca/weblog/forcing-ssl-in-a-sinatra-app)" about forcing SSL in Sinatra applications and how it could be helpful to your situation.

Comment: Please see  "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"